# Extract JobID etc from Hadoop Job

Tags: java, ubuntu, hadoop

I am running a Hadoop jar file inside a cluster. From the documentation, I know that Hadoop manages JobID, Start time etc. Is it possible to get the parameters so that we can show them on our web interface just to let user know how much time the job will consume (e.g. estimated duration)?

Answer (score 0):

All the details shown in the Jobtracker UI can be obtained easily by using the APIs provided.

Use **jobclient** API refer : https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobClient.html
 and **Jobstatus** api refer : https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobStatus.html

Using the combination of jobclient and jobstatus(jobsToComplete(), getAllJobs() ) you can retrieve the JobId . Once you get the jobId you can easily get all the other details by just calling the functions in the API.